# DJI Mobile SDK, Android Studio Emulator SDK Registration Failed

Tags: android, android-emulator, registration, dji-sdk

I have an issue with the SDK registration while using an android studio emulator!

I just tried to use the app sample "ImportSDK" from [this link](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-ImportAndActivateSDKInAndroidStudio)

But the app shows me directly

> "Register SDK failed, check if network is available"

On my real android device **"Samsung Galaxy Tab A6" it is working!**

But I need to use the Android Emulator to use it in a combination with the DJI Android Bridge.

I hope someone can show me the right way to use an App with the DJI Mobile SDK on an android studio emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The DJI mobile sdk does not work with the emulator. Instead load the app on an android device.